# Bootstrap Datepicker on change firing 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi I have been trying to just get the date of a bootstrap date picker and have been able to but it seems to fires 3 times. NOTE: This is not jquery date picker but bootstrap date picker.

Using this date picker: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker, not older eyecon.ro one.

```
 $(".date-picker").on("change", function(e) {
      contents = $(this).val();
      id = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log("onchange contents: " + contents);
      console.log("onchange id: " + id);

 });
```

HTML:

```
<input id="start_date" type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" class="date-picker form-control" />
```

I have used a few other options other than change, like

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker().change(function(){};
```

But this does not close date picker, hoping there is an easy solution to this. thx

Comment: I think the bug tracker for this issue is here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/912

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it does not fix the problem, but i was using the datepicker to send through an ajax post, so the 3 change events was causing me problems - the 3rd event always failed.  even if the documentation says to use a changeDate event, it doesn't seem right to me to fire the input tag's change event 3 times.  the value isn't changing 3 times!

I wrote a simple 'debounce' function to get around the problem.  doesn't fix the issue - which is due to multiple change events being fired from the methods: setValue (line 508) _setDate:(line 1048) and setValue (line 508) (version 1.3.0)  of the widget.

```
 var lastJQueryTS = 0 ;// this is a global variable.
 ....
 // in the change event handler...
    var send = true;
if (typeof(event) == 'object'){
    if (event.timeStamp - lastJQueryTS < 300){
        send = false;
    }
    lastJQueryTS = event.timeStamp;
}
if (send){
    post_values(this);
}
```

it is pretty simple, just finds the jquery 'event', and makes sure that values in a window of 300ms are ignored.  in my testing this all happened in 30 msec or so.

Comment: This is clever trick like you said it won't fix the problem but it surely does help a bit.

Comment: do you have copy of this modified of yours? i had same porblems here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699007/highstock-inputdateparser-fires-three-times?noredirect=1#comment40285939_25699007

Answer (score 39):

You should be using the "changeDate" event. For example:

```
var datePicker = $('.date-picker').datePicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    //Functionality to be called whenever the date is changed
});
```

Please view the documentation [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) for more info on this event.

Comment: I am not using that date picker, that version has a bug with the auto close. Whenever I select a date it won't close. 

Using this one:
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: There seems to be the 'changeDate' event on your version as well, take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L1216). Did you try it?

Comment: yes tried the same line as yours above and date picker would not auto close. Perhaps this other version works different?

Comment: This worked for me when I created this event: `$(document).on('changeDate', function() {});` separate from my original event: `var datePicker = $('input#date-picker').datePicker()`

Comment: this is the best and simplest way, thank you very much

Comment: if somebody still gets multiple changeDate fired  use following code   
                                                                                                             var datePicker = $('.date-picker').datePicker().off('changeDate').on('changeDate', function(ev) {
 
});

Answer (score 4):

As some has mentioned already, use this:

```
$('#calendar').on("changeDate", function() {

});
```

The trick is to use `changeDate` instead of `change`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if when checking the `change` event, if the change was from actual **user interaction**, the change event contains a value for `originalEvent`.

The event **does NOT** contain this value if the input was changed via JS:
`$obj.val('1990-03-07').change()` and the same with bootstrap-datepicker

## Here's how I set it up:

### Generic initial setup

```
// General selector for date inputs
var $obj = $('input[type="date"]');

$obj.datepicker({
    // options here, not important for this example
});
```

### Handle `bootstrap-datepicker` specific changes

```
$obj.datepicker().on('changeDate', function (event) {
    handleInputDateAndTimeChange(event);
});
```

### Now, deal with **user interaction** changes

```
$('input[type="date"], input[type="time"]').change(function (event) {
    // This checks if change was initiated by user input and NOT JS
    if(event.originalEvent !== undefined) {
        handleInputDateAndTimeChange(event);
    }
});
```

### And finally, here's the `handleInputDateAndTimeChange` function

```
function handleInputDateAndTimeChange(event) {
    var $input = $(event.target);

    // Do what you want with $input object here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer from #pgee70 and it doesn't work for me. So this is my solution, hope its help

```
var send=true;

 $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
     todayBtn: "linked",
     keyboardNavigation: false,
     forceParse: false,
     language: 'es-ES',
     weekStart: 1,
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     enableOnReadonly:false,
     calendarWeeks: true,
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight:true
 }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
     if(send){
        modificarFechaAplicacionCliente($("#input_filtro_fecha_cliente").val());
        send=false;
     }

     setTimeout(function(){send=true;},200);
 });
```

It´s not a beaty solution, but it´s work.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the above answer, but you should use *datepicker* unless you've renamed the function:

```
var datePicker = $('.date-picker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    //Functionality to be called whenever the date is changed
});
```

This works for me, except in my case, I renamed the function to *datepickerBootstrap* to avoid the clash with JQuery's. So then it would become:

```
var datePicker = $('.date-picker').datepickerBootstrap().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    // On change functionality
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed find your fixed js datepicker file [HERE](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js)

Read fixing description [HERE](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/pull/1337)

Answer (score 1):

**I have faced the same problem with bootstrap-datepicker when it used with the jQuery OnChange event they call function 3 times. Here is my code**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CmpStartDate, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", new { @size = "30", @class = "form-control search-date", @placeholder = "Start date" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CmpEndDate, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", new { @size = "30", @class = "form-control search-date", @placeholder = "End date" })  


<script>
$('#CmpStartDate,#CmpEndDate').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      minViewMode: 3,
      format: "dd-M-yyyy"
});

$(".search-date").on("change", function () {
     cmpStartDate = $("#CmpStartDate").val();
     cmpEndDate = $("#CmpEndDate").val();
     SearchThisDateRecords(cmpStartDate,cmpEndDate);
});

function SearchThisDateRecords(cmpStartDate,cmpEndDate) {
console.log("Call search method");
}
</script>
```

**We need to call this function only one time, Not multiple time so you can use the below logic to fix this problem**

```
<script>
    $('#CmpStartDate,#CmpEndDate').datepicker({
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true,
          minViewMode: 3,
          format: "dd-M-yyyy"
    });

    var i = 0;

    $(".search-date").on("change", function () {
         cmpStartDate = $("#CmpStartDate").val();
         cmpEndDate = $("#CmpEndDate").val();
         SearchThisDateRecords(cmpStartDate,cmpEndDate);

         i++;
         console.log(i);
         if (i == 3) {
             SearchThisDateRecords(cmpStartDate,cmpEndDate);
         }
    });
    function SearchThisDateRecords(cmpStartDate,cmpEndDate) {
         i =0; //Reset i value
         console.log("Call search method");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get global variable count and check if equal to 0 then execute Your function.

```
var count=0;
     $( "#Id" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0}).on('change',function (){
            if(count==0) 
           validity();//any function
           count=1;
         });
     validity(){ count=0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

bit annoying..
my code was:

```
var c=0;var send=false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( ".ed" ).datepicker({ 
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            autoclose:!0
        }).on('change',function() {
            if(c==2){
                c=0;
                send=true;
            }else{
                c++;
                send=false;
            }                
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use changeDate function in place of change .

Answer (score 0):

```
var LastController =['id','value']; //global variable...
 function datepeakerchange(e){ 

 if ((LastController[0] != e.target.id && LastController[1] != e.target.value) || (LastController[0] == e.target.id && LastController[1] != e.target.value)) {

            LastController[0] = e.target.id;
            LastController[1] = e.target.value;


    write your code....


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var pickerFireCount = 0;

function checkSelectedDateIsHollyday(rId) {
  pickerFireCount++;
  if (pickerFireCount == 3) {
    if (!selectedDateIsHolyday(rId)) {
      showInfoMessage('The date you selected is a holiday.');
      pickerFireCount = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: = $('.date-picker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function is didn't work field in line onchange event above code block was work