# Highstock inputDateParser fires three times

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bootstrap-datepicker

I am not sure what cause it to fire three times after selecting a date through [date calendar](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/index.html). Here is the options set for `rangeSelector`

```
rangeSelector:{
    enabled:true,
    inputEnabled: true,
    inputDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
    inputEditDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',                    
    inputDateParser: function (value) {
        value = value.split('/');
        console.log(value);
        return Date.UTC(
          parseInt(value[0]),
          parseInt(value[1]) - 1,
          parseInt(value[2])
        );
    }
}
```

by using `backbone.view` jquery selector, here how i initiate the chart

`this.$el.highcharts(Options, this.extra);`

and `extra` as additional settings to trigger the date picker

```
highlightSer: function (chart){         
      setTimeout(function () {              
         $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $(chart.container).parent())
            .datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",    
                todayBtn: "linked",
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                orientation: "auto right"
            });             
      }, 0);            
}
```

is anyone experience this?

Comment: Could you provide live demo, like jsfiddle? Thanks.

Comment: hi Pawel, here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muhaimincs/L093jc7k/

Comment: Well, the issue is for sure with that calendar. Once removed it works fine (just one call): http://jsfiddle.net/L093jc7k/10/. Anyway, you had error when using `Date.UTC()`, order of values was wrong(above example has fixed this). Then, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614041/bootstrap-datepicker-on-change-firing-3-times) about datepicker called three times.

Comment: Thanks for your fixes. BTW, whenever I enter a date earlier than July 1987, highchart will take it back to July 1987. Is this a bug?

Comment: You can browse dates available on the chart only.

Comment: thanks @PawełFus. I read somewhere there is a plugin for us to query out of extreme.. That really help. I just think that plugin should be incorporated in highchart

Comment: Yes, there's plugin for that. Since there's plugin, why should be this inside of the core?

Answer (score 2):

@seeARMS solution from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614041/bootstrap-datepicker-on-change-firing-3-times) worked for me, with one modification:

**Create a separate function for your event**

One function has the datePicker method and your settings:

```
$('input_with_date_picker').datePicker({...});
```

A separate function controls your `on changeDate` event:

```
$(document).on('changeDate', 'input_with_date_picker', function({..do something..}));
```

or:

```
$('input_with_date_picker').on('changeDate', function({..do something..}));
```

#### Update:

[The fiddle you provided](http://jsfiddle.net/muhaimincs/L093jc7k/12/) in the comments is working as expected because of your added function:

```
$('input.highcharts-range-selector').on('changeDate', function(e) {
    alert(e.date);                                     
});
```

On page load, it executes twice because you have two elements that match. They seem to both be generated by this JS:

```
rangeSelector:{
        enabled:true,
        inputEnabled:true,
        inputDateFormat:"%d/%m",
        inputEditDateFormat:"%d/%m/%Y",
        inputDateParser: function (value) {
            value = value.split('/');
            console.log(value);
            return Date.UTC(
                parseInt(value[0]),
                parseInt(value[1]) - 1,
                parseInt(value[2])
            );
        }       
    },
```

If you change the date on either of the elements, the function executes once, which is the goal of your post.

You may be indicating it's not working because the dates aren't updating when you select a new date from the datePicker. I'm not sure why this is, I'm not familiar with highcharts.

Comment: this is not solution for **Highchart**. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/muhaimincs/L093jc7k/12/)

Comment: It seems to be working just fine. The code is firing twice because you have two elements that meet this criteria: `$('input.highcharts-range-selector')`: the From input and the To input. If it weren't, the code would be firing 6 times, 3 for each input.

Comment: I don't get you. Could you provide sample jsFiddle?

Comment: Ha! That's what my wife says! Your fiddle is my sample because your fiddle is working as expected. See my update.