# datepicker.js update date when date is updated by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I am using a library called  [bootstrap-datepicker.js](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (not using the latest version though).

I have a calendar input which I want to update to the closest monday once the user has picked a date. To be able to do that I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="data">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input id="control-monday" value="01/01/2000" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#data .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: "0d"
}).on('changeDate', DateUpdated);


function DateUpdated(e) {  

    PickedDate = e.date; 
    //Finding monday
    monday = ....;

    $("#control-monday").datepicker("setDate", monday);
    $("#control-monday").val(monday);


}
```

The issue is that every time I update the date to the closest monday using DateUpdated(), the function is fired again since the date was updated and becomes a infinite loop. Is there a way to only fire the function DateUpdated() only when a user  manually picked a date and not when Jquery does it?

to explain a bit farther of what is happening:

1. User pick a date
2. DateUpdated() is called due to `.on('changeDate', DateUpdated);`
3. The date is updated to the closest monday `$("#control-monday").datepicker("setDate", monday);`
4. Because the date was changed in point 3 DateUpdated() is called AGAIN due to `.on('changeDate', DateUpdated);`
5. 3 and 4 go for ever.

I am currently using a global variable to count how many times the function has been called and only firing it when is the first time and restarting the count after 2 calls but it's a bit ugly and very unstable.

Comment: I finally 'fixed" this by updating bootstrap datepicker to the latest version to stop the re-firing .on('changeDate'). Also, Ajax was re-firing multiple times events so I fixed it following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614041/bootstrap-datepicker-on-change-firing-3-times#22614264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional flag.

```
function DateUpdated(e, flag) {  
    if (typeof flag === "undefined") {
         // call when user manually picked
    }
}
```

So when you try to call DateUpdated from your code, you can call `DateUpdated(e, true);`

If it is hard to add flag when you call from your code, you can  add flag when event is trigger.

```
$('#data .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: "0d"
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    DateUpdated(e, true);
});

function DateUpdated(e, flag) {  
    if (typeof flag !== "undefined") {
         // call when user manually picked
    }
}
```

Okay, since you only want to find the closest Monday and prevent infinite loop. You can always do something like this:

```
function DateUpdated(e) {  

    PickedDate = e.date; 
    //Finding monday
    monday = ....;

    if (monday !== e.date) {
       $("#control-monday").datepicker("setDate", monday);
       $("#control-monday").val(monday);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am currently using flags to count the number of firings the function has and only fires at the first one but is very ugly. I cant send any arguments in the function DateUpdated() due to library limitations.

Comment: neither worked. The issue is when Jquery changes the date here: `$("#control-monday").datepicker("setDate", monday)` the DateUpdate() function is trigger automatically without my control due to `.on('changeDate' DateUpdated)` so whether I send true or undefined the function's arguments will remain the same whether is the user or Jquery. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @Joe, don't give up, I will come with a way  :P

Comment: Thanks @ivisal I updated my question as well to give more clarity. The issue is when I call ´("setDate", monday);´ DateUpdated() fires because the date was updated.

Comment: The flag solved my issue but it's kind of ugly. Thank you @invisal.