# Change function on datetimepicker not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have used datetimepicker in my project. But when I am using the change event to call the ajax function it is being called multiple times.

Also when running the script on browser with an alert on change function it goes into infinite state where the alert doesn't seems to remove even after close button.

Version of Datetimepicker used: 3.1.12

```
$("#timepickerstartt").change(function(){
  alert();
});
```

Snippet used for datetimepicker

**Note:** I have tried the **onselect** event but no luck.

```
$('#cashing_start_time').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  theme:'dark',
  format:'H:i',
  onChange: function(selectedDate) {
      alert();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you are too close...
you can use this function

```
$('#timepickerstartt').on('dp.change', function(e){ console.log(e.date); })
```

see this [link](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) for more details

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jpmkcr5/1136/)

Comment: Still not working...there are no logs in the console showing date or time on change event..Also I could find the dp in the elements on browser not sure if that is how it works!!

Comment: check jsfiddle in answer

Comment: yes..the fiddle worked but not in my codebase and this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614041/bootstrap-datepicker-on-change-firing-3-times] helped finally overcome it.